# How to get `this` in jest mock function

Tags: jestjs

I have the below code, which mocks a function `fetchAge` of `Person`. I need to conditionally return a value based on the value of `this`, but `this` is an empty object in the function. Is there any way to do this in Jest?

```
jest.unmock('Person');
const Person = require('Person');

Query.prototype.fetchAge = jest.fn(() => {
    console.log(this); // this returns an empty object
    if(this.name === 'Bob') return 21;
    if(this.name === 'Joe') return 19;
});

test('verify correct ages', function() {
  const bob = new Person('Bob');
  expect(bob.fetchAge).toEqual(21);
});
```

Comment: Please provide the code of `Person.fetchAge` method

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to assert anything on the mocked `fetchAge` method (like `fetchAge.mock.calls.length` for example) you could simply assign the `fetchAge` method to a new function without using `jest.fn`.

E.g.

```
Query.prototype.fetchAge = () => {
    console.log(this); // this returns an empty object
    if(this.name === 'Bob') return 21;
    if(this.name === 'Joe') return 19;
};
```

I think that way `this` will relate to the correct object (here `bob`).